Percentage composition of mixtures
A sample of clay contains 40% sillica and 15% water. The sample is partially dried by which it loses 5 gm water. If the percentage of water in the partially dried clay is 8, calculate the percentage of silica in the partially dried clay.
a)21.33% b)43.29% c)75% d)50%
Now, I have seen other answers and here is the problem.

Considering 100g of mixture, we have 40 g silica and 15 g water. Now, removing 5g water gives us 10g water, total 95 g mixture left. One answer mentions that The new amount of silica in the clay = 95 - 10 = 85 grams. And then it says (x/100) x 95 = 85. So, x=43.29. Firstly, how this equation came is unknown. Secondly, the amount of silica in the clay is NOT 85 because there are other impurities, 60% in original clay.

Another answer goes like this -
In the original sample, 40/85 is
the content of silica. Now, the dried clay contains 8% water, so non water content is 92. So percentage is, 40/85×92. However there's a big issue here. In the dried clay, non water content is NOT 8g, because the clay in total is 95g only, and it's 8% = 95×8% = 7.6g and not 8g. This gives very close, but still not correct option, of 43.48.

My approach :-


Suppose we have X grams of mixture. Content of water is X × 15%.
Drying out we get, (X × 15%) - 5g of water in new mixture.
I assumed that mass of other components Silica and impurities not decreased while drying out.
It's given that percentage of water is 8% in new mixture.
Also, new mixture must have less mass than original X.
∴ ( X × 15%) - 5 ≤ X × 8%
Solving this I got,
X ≤ 500/7.
Now, let percentage of silica be Y.
Y = mass of silica/ Total Mass × 100
We get that Y inversely proportional to X.
So for maximum X = 500/7
∴ minimum Y = (max(X) - 5)× 40%
Solving I got,
Y ≥ 186 /7
Y ≥ 26.57
Still, I cannot find the value of Y.

I've deleted that comment, yeah, it was confusing. Apologies. And yes, you are correct that there is not said that initial mass is 100g. Can you please provide correct solution, answer to the question

The approach 2 has no big issue. It is obvious the water content in the partly dried sample is not 8 g. But this fact is irrelevant. the relevant fact is water makes 8 %.  //  Consider formatting guides for texts and formulas/equations/expressions

You can determine the right answer even without any calculation, by comparing relative numbers.
It cannot be a) as the relative silica content cannot decrease by drying. It cannot be c) not d) either, as the relative drying loss is not that high. So it must be b).
To calculate it,
$$\text{silica final %} =  \dfrac {\text{final dry %}}{\text{initial dry %}} \cdot \text{silica initial %}$$
$$40\ \%  \cdot \dfrac {92\ \% }{85\ \%} \approx 43.29\ \%.$$
So the answer is b).
The absolute water loss and the sample mass are excessive, misleading, non-essential info, except for the former proportionally determining the latter. But the relative composition of the partially dried sample with the given final relative water content does not depend on the sample mass nor on the absolute mass of lost water.

Thank you. As a learning student, can I know HOW do we conclude that absolute water loss and sample mass are misleading, and non essential info? I can see that it's misleading after you pointed it out, but how can I understand that myself?

Because all the task is about relative, not absolute values, that do not depend on sample mass nor absolute water loss. Silica makes a fixed percentual part of percentual dry content and proportionally follows it's changes.

In fact, this eventual difficulty does not come from chemistry, but from math. Your  procedural mistake was you have not done proper analysis of the task and have not converted it to a purely mathemathical problem. You have more or less jumped directly to attempts to compute the result, without actually being aware of what the task is mathematically about.
